# (PDO) Insert database data into an array and use in_array to echo data

Tags: php, pdo

My problem is that I cannot insert data into an array from the database, and then echo out a specific string or text using the in_array function. What am I doing wrong? 
This is the code for what I have attempted.

```
<?php
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=driving','root','');
    $sel = "SELECT first_name, civ_licenses FROM users";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sel);
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $arrayResult = $row['civ_licenses'];
        $civArray = array($arrayResult);
        if(in_array('`license_civ_driving`,1', $civArray)){
            echo $row['first_name'], 'has got the driving license';
        }
    }
    die;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "There was an error with your code!" . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

 ?>
```

Comment: `\`license_civ_driving\`,1` is likely not an index. You also overwrite the `civArray` on every iteration. Why not just use a `where` clause if you want to test something?

Comment: @chris85 I had WHERE first_name = 'Bob' before. Couldn't find a solution to my problem.

Comment: What is your goal? You want to find if `Bob` has a license, determined by the value of `license_civ_driving` being 1 for yes and 0 for no?

Comment: @chris85 To store a specific users 'civ_licenses' which is a field in my database into an array and then pick out specific strings of that 'civ_licenses' for validation as to whether a user has it or not.

Comment: @chris85 This is what is stored in the 'civ_licenses' currently: "[[`license_civ_driver`,1],[`license_civ_boat`,0]]"

Comment: This makes no sense `$arrayResult = $row['civ_licenses']; $civArray = array($arrayResult); if(in_array('1', $civArray))`  you turn 1 item into an array to check it, why no just do `if($row['civ_licenses'] == '1')` ?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix That was a mistake I made on my behalf, edited the code to the original.

Comment: @TibbeUSDF - I doubt that, that is what is in that array.  That might be what you think is in there.  Or this is not the actual code.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix It is the actual code. I'm not sure if the data is being stored in the array, thats why I am asking if anyone has an easier way of doing or a solution.

Comment: 100% there are easier ways. I don't exactly know what you are doing though. You can use a `case` in the query itself and append the `has got the driving license` to the row's value. From what I can tell you have users that are identified by `first_name` only?? Being a `Chris` I don't think you're going to find my license correctly.

Comment: Well I can tell you it's not, you should do `var_export($row)` and do `var_export($civArray)` and you will see.

Comment: @chris85 Okay, I'm going to give an example of what I want my code to do. Selects all the data on the field 'civ_licenses' from the user: 'Bob' whoms first name is stored in the database under 'first_name'. I want to store all the data for 'civ_licenses' on Bobs record into an array and then pick out specific strings so I can do a bunch of validation.

Comment: Can you add 3 DB records and what you want the PHP to do with them?

Comment: Dont store comma seperated lists of data in a single column. Have a quick look at a beginners How To Design A Database Tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do

```
$sel = "SELECT first_name, civ_licenses FROM users";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sel);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
```

It will give you something like this

```
 [
     'bob' => [
           ['civ_licenses1'],
           ['civ_licenses2'],
     ], 'alice' => [
       ....
     ]
 ]
```

It groups them on the first column, in this case `first_name`.  This is also different then using `GROUP BY` in SQL.

Then you can loop though them

```
foreach($data as $first_name => $civ_array){
   ...
}
```

So using my data above the first iteration would give you this

```
$first_name = 'bob'
$civ_array = [
       ['civ_licenses1'],
       ['civ_licenses2'],
 ];
```

Comment: I think you are going to have to give a few more clues than that. The OP is obviously a beginner and does not understand what they are trying to do

Comment: I had planed on it.

Answer (score 0):

If I correct understand, your code should be like this:

```
<?php
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=driving','root','');
    $sel = "SELECT first_name, civ_licenses FROM users";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sel);
    $stmt->execute();
    $civArray = array();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        $civArray[] = $row['civ_licenses'];
        if(in_array('`license_civ_driving`,1', $civArray)){
            echo $row['first_name'], 'has got the driving license';
        }

    }
    die;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "There was an error with your code!" . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
```

1. first you need declare empty array

   $civArray = array();
2. you can use fetch_style like PDO::FETCH_ASSOC http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

   $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
3. on each iteration you add value to array

   $civArray[] = $row['civ_licenses'];
4. and check license value in this array

   ```
   if(in_array('`license_civ_driving`,1', $civArray)){
       echo $row['first_name'], 'has got the driving license';
   }
   ```